# How to install DownThemAll API to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, download-manager

I want to install DownThemAll API to my website so that my visitors can download videos from my website using DownThemAll. In order for you to understand here is the code that I want to use [site](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2709131), but somehow I am not able to use [Downthemall API](https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall-mirror/tree/master/modules). I tried to use:

```
<script src="#locationofAPI/api.js"></script>
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to include this API and how should I do that?

Thanks